# How to insert a hyphen between blocks of alpha and numeric characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to insert hyphens between blocks of alpha and numeric text in a string.
I am not even sure how to start on this problem.

```
ABC123 -> ABC-123
ABC123XYZ -> ABC-123-XYZ
D123 -> D-123
123C -> 123-C
```

Comment: Why downvotes o.O ?

Comment: Are these column values in a table or variables?

Comment: @ShakeerMirza. Maybe for many reasons, 1) The OP didn't show us what he did for now for fixing this, 2) the SO site is not a generated code tool., maybe other reasons. (BTW: I am not the downvoter.)

Comment: @artm They are column data in a table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one will work for you with single value.

```
DECLARE @CODE VARCHAR(50) = '12ABC123XYZ'
    ,@NEWCODE VARCHAR(100) = ''

;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT NUMBER
        ,SUBSTRING(@CODE, NUMBER, 1) AS VAL
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    WHERE TYPE = 'P'
        AND number BETWEEN 1
            AND LEN(@CODE)
    )
SELECT @NEWCODE = @NEWCODE + CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(C1.VAL) <> ISNUMERIC(ISNULL(C2.VAL, C1.VAL))
            THEN '-' + C1.VAL
        ELSE C1.VAL
        END
FROM CTE C1
LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.number = C2.number + 1

SELECT @NEWCODE
```

**Result :**  12-ABC-123-XYZ

And If you want this to work with table column, you need to create a scalar function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CODE_SPLIT  
(

    @CODE VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN

     DECLARE @NEWCODE VARCHAR(100) ='';

    ;WITH CTE
    AS (
        SELECT NUMBER
            ,SUBSTRING(@CODE, NUMBER, 1) AS VAL
        FROM master.dbo.spt_values
        WHERE TYPE = 'P'
            AND number BETWEEN 1
                AND LEN(@CODE)
        )
    SELECT @NEWCODE = @NEWCODE + CASE 
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(C1.VAL) <> ISNUMERIC(ISNULL(C2.VAL, C1.VAL))
                THEN '-' + C1.VAL
            ELSE C1.VAL
            END
    FROM CTE C1
    LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.number = C2.number + 1

    RETURN @NEWCODE

END
GO
```

And call it on your actual table

**Schema:**

```
SELECT *  INTO #TAB FROM(
SELECT 'ABC123' AS CODE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC123XYZ'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'D123'
UNION ALL
SELECT '123C'
)A

SELECT CODE, dbo.CODE_SPLIT(CODE) AS NEWCODE FROM #TAB
```

**Result:**

```
+-----------+-------------+
|   CODE    |   NEWCODE   |
+-----------+-------------+
| ABC123    | ABC-123     |
| ABC123XYZ | ABC-123-XYZ |
| D123      | D-123       |
| 123C      | 123-C       |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Super code broo..mind blowing frankly...you rock for ever with mesmerizing coding skills .. i'm missing all this stuff from u... really sad  (|:-

Answer (score 1):

`patindex('%[0-9]%')` return index of first number. 
`patindex('%[^0-9]%')` return index of first non-numeric character. 
You could use `recursive CTE` and [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql) like this.

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
   TextValue varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES ('ABC124'), ('ABC123XYZ'), ('123C'), ('ABC'), ('1A2B3C')

;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT    sd.TextValue AS RootText,
         sd.TextValue AS CurrentText, 
         CAST('' AS varchar(100)) AS Result
   FROM @SampleData sd

   UNION ALL

      SELECT    
            c.RootText,
            CASE       
                   WHEN patindex('%[0-9]%', c.CurrentText) = 0 OR patindex('%[^0-9]%', c.CurrentText) = 0
                      THEN ''
                   WHEN patindex('%[0-9]%', c.CurrentText) > patindex('%[^0-9]%', c.CurrentText) 
                      THEN RIGHT(c.CurrentText, len(c.CurrentText) - patindex('%[0-9]%', c.CurrentText) + 1)
                   ELSE RIGHT(c.CurrentText, len(c.CurrentText) - patindex('%[^0-9]%', c.CurrentText) + 1)
            END AS CurrentText, 
            CAST(
                  CASE 
                      WHEN patindex('%[0-9]%', c.CurrentText) = 0 OR patindex('%[^0-9]%', c.CurrentText) = 0
                            THEN Result + '-' + c.CurrentText
                      WHEN patindex('%[0-9]%', c.CurrentText) > patindex('%[^0-9]%', c.CurrentText) 
                            THEN Result + '-' + LEFT(CurrentText, patindex('%[0-9]%', c.CurrentText) - 1)
                      ELSE Result + '-' + LEFT(CurrentText, patindex('%[^0-9]%', c.CurrentText) - 1)
                  END AS varchar(100)
                ) AS Result
   FROM cte c
   WHERE LEN(CurrentText) > 0
)
SELECT cte.RootText, STUFF(cte.Result, 1,1,'') AS Result FROM cte
WHERE cte.CurrentText = ''
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/FTYA72053